# count of events per month to run line plot

Tags: r

I have a dataset where every row correspond to a participant. It has a categorical variable called "Injury.Cause"

```
          Injury.Date.Time                         Injury.Cause
3608 2019-05-22 00:00:00                        Motor Vehicle
3915 2019-03-25 10:00:00                           Accidental
3916 2019-03-25 16:00:00                              Burn
3917 2019-03-25 10:00:00                           Accidental
3920 2019-03-25 00:00:00                               Fall
3928 2019-03-27 00:00:00                               Fall 
3929 2019-03-26 21:50:00                        Motor Vehicle
3930 2019-03-27 17:00:00                               Fall 
3931 2019-03-26 00:00:00                        Motor Vehicleter
```

I want to run line plot with multiple lines (each line represent a cause of injury over time) and the y-axis shows the total number of occurrence(frequency)/month for each cause of injury

I assume the first step is I have to make my data ordered as follow

```
   Date     Motor Vehicle   Accidental    Burn   Fall  
2021-03-22         3              2          1       2
2021-03-23         1               1          0       3
```

this example is shown in days but I believe I can control the time frame when making the plot. I will be exploring the changes across periods of 3 months intervals on the x-axis

Thank you in advance

Rami

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get the data in required structure using `table` after extracting the date from timestamp.

```
table(as.Date(df$Injury.Date.Time), df$Injury.Cause)
```

Or in `tidyverse` -

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  count(Date = as.Date(Injury.Date.Time), Injury.Cause) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Injury.Cause, values_from = n, values_fill = 0)

#   Date       Accidental  Burn  Fall `Motor Vehicle` `Motor Vehicleter`
#  <date>          <int> <int> <int>           <int>              <int>
#1 2019-03-25          2     1     1               0                  0
#2 2019-03-26          0     0     0               1                  1
#3 2019-03-27          0     0     2               0                  0
#4 2019-05-22          0     0     0               1                  0
```

---

However, if you want to plot the data you should have data in long format and not in wide format.

```
df %>%
  count(Date = as.Date(Injury.Date.Time), Injury.Cause) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(Date, n, color = Injury.Cause) + geom_line()
```